# Argument passing by auto in range based for

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop

```
vector<MyClass> objects;
for (auto obj : objects)
{}
```

Will `obj` be a copy of each object or a reference?

Comment: "It'll be a reference right?" - looks at answers below - "oh." - dives into code-base to make sure I've not introduced some major bugs...  I pretty much assumed the `obj` would be equivalent to `(*iterator)` in your typical iterator based for loop.  Good thing I've not used this in anger yet.

Comment: `auto` uses the same rules as template argument deduction. Therefore `auto` by itself is similar to a template parameter by value, which will make copies for lvalues and moves for rvalues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you will get a copy for each element, you won't with `auto&` or `auto&&`. This [is better understood with an example](http://ideone.com/YHL86D)

```
struct MyClass {
    MyClass() {}
    MyClass(const MyClass&) {
        cout << "copy ctor invoked" << endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    vector<MyClass> objects;
    MyClass obj1;
    objects.push_back(obj1); // Vector filling
    cout << "------" << endl;
    for (auto obj : objects) // Auto loop
    {}
    cout << "------" << endl;
    for (auto& obj : objects)
    {}
}
```

Output:

```
copy ctor invoked // Vector filling
------
copy ctor invoked // Auto loop
------
```

Answer (score 10):

The way written you will get a copy for every element. To not get a copy, use

```
for (auto&& obj: object) {
}
```

You can also use one of the other obvious variations:

1. Still with the type deduced but be explicit about using a reference: `auto&`.
2. Be explicit but use a `const` reference: `auto const&`.
3. You can actually also use the type: `MyClass&` or `MyClass const&`.

Comment: @cdhowie: you'd get the type deduced but it would be required to be a reference. Interestingly, the code would fail to compile if `MyClass` happens to be `bool` (or, more generally, if the iterator returns a proxy).

Comment: If I want read only access should I use `auto&&` or `const auto&`

Comment: What's the (practical) different between `auto &&` and `const auto &`?

Comment: @Neil: if you want to guarantee read-only access, you'd used `auto const&` as `auto&&` will deduce the exact kind of type based on what `*it` returns (where `it` is of the corresponding iterator type). In the above setup `auto&&` would result in a `MyClass&` being used while `auto const&` would result in `MyClass const&`.

Comment: @NPS: well, `auto&&` can deduces three different kinds of types depending on the type of `*it` (where `it` is an object of the corresponding iterator type): If it is an iterator to a non-`const` container, `auto&&` will result in a `MyClass&` while `auto const&` will result in a `MyClass const&` (assuming normal iterators, if the iterator returns a proxy as is the case for `std::vector<bool>`, the type of `auto&&` will deduce the proxy type).

Comment: @DietmarKühl: An example for the proxy-fail you spoke of: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2028ea1ae9d513a3

Comment: @Deduplicator, The example is very good because it shows that `auto const&` also can work with proxies.

Comment: @alfC: How does that detract from the point of the example, which is that `auto&` is not right when proxies intervene?

Comment: @Deduplicator, I don't know, I am just saying that if one needs a read-only variable, `auto const&` seems to work in all cases, including if one doesn't know if a proxy is going to be generated. right?

Comment: @alfC: Sure it does. But we don't know it should be read-only.

Comment: @Deduplicator, thanks for the clarification. My idea was to see if one can state intention and also avoid changing the value inside the loop by imposing `const` somehow (without necessarily the range being `const`). (My first reaction was to incorrectly do a `for{auto const&& obj : ...)`)

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is: your intuition is correct and you get a copy.

The reason behind that lies with the type deduced by `auto`. Scott Mayers gave a talk recently at CppCon 2014 on this topic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQxj20X-tIU